# composer works every where except one project

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I'm beginner in yii2. `composer command` works in **every path** in windows 10, but in one of my project's path `composer command` not works. Actually does nothing at all.

It's obviously in this image:

[image]

I don't know the the reason.

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "franciscomaya/yii2-sceditor": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*",
        "mohammad-mahdy/yii2-jdate": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget": "~1.0",
        "romka-chev/yii2-swiper": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-checkbox-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev",
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"

    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you have composer.phar in this folder?

Comment: @leo_ap yes I have composer.phar