# Error in creating yii2 project with composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

I want to create **yii2** project in windows 10. I use `composer create-project`command truly, but I against with error.

Here is `composer create-project` command in **Command Prompt**:

[image]

And of course I get the same error in `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"`:

[image]

I had no `composer.json` file in folder `C:/Users/Mohammad/AppData/Roaming/Composer` after installing [composer-setup.exe](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe), and I copied `composer.json` file from one of my projects in folder `C:/Users/Mohammad/AppData/Roaming/Composer`.

This is my composer.json in folder `C:/Users/Mohammad/AppData/Roaming/Composer`:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "franciscomaya/yii2-sceditor": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*",
        "mohammad-mahdy/yii2-jdate": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget": "~1.0",
        "romka-chev/yii2-swiper" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "*",
        "omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart": "*",
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"

    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Did you forget to install [composer asset plugin](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-from-composer)?

Comment: I have **the same error** in `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"` command

Comment: I don't understand.... You say that when you run `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"` command in console you get error about bower-asset/jquery?

Comment: yes exactly. I get error about bower-asset/jquery.

Comment: You must show us the way you are running this command in console because there is no way you can get the error about jquery.

Comment: @MohammadAghayari delete the folder basic in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic and try a smooth installation again as I have given below in the answer

Comment: @Bizley I added image of command prompt to explain better my problem.

Comment: @MohammadAghayari could you add image of using `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"` as well?

Comment: @Bizley I added the image.

Comment: @MohammadAghayari which composer version are you using

Comment: @Kiran Muralee I have dowloaded form https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe . How can I know witch version it is?

Comment: type composer in command line and hit enter

Comment: @Kiran Muralee The composer works in `composer` command perfectly. there is no error on it.

Comment: As @Bizley suggested please open your composer.json and tell us what's inside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problems in installing `yii2` project using composer in my windows 10 system. Delete the folder `basic` or `yii2Basic` inside `C:\xampp\htdocs` and follow these steps for smooth installation.

1. Check composer is installed on your system. You can check this by typing `composer` in your command line and hitting enter. If composer is successfully installed you will see a screen like this.

   [image]
2. Next step is to install the `Composer Asset Plugin`.Before that you need to remove the folder `composer` from `C:/Users/Mohammad/AppData/Roaming/Composer` if one is there.Then Run the following command to install it.

> composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"

[image]

3. Now navigate to the directory you wish to maintain your source code.In your case it would be

> cd C:\xampp\htdocs

4. Now to install the basic application template run the command below.

> composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.10

In the process you might see a screen as given below asking you to input token.

[image]

This is normal just login to your github account and paste the `url` given to generate the token.The copied token is then pasted for the installation to continue.Sometimes you might be asked to enter your github username and password,these are normal just follow the steps and you are ready to go.

If still the problem persists check the contents inside of your `composer.json`

Contents inside my `composer.json` is given below

```
{
    "require": {
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no folder like `basic` inside `C:\xampp\htdocs` . Do you mean folder `yii2Basic`?

Comment: And I get the same error in running `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"` command.

Comment: please delete yii2Basic and try again with the steps given above by me

Comment: could you post the image of error when given the command  composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"

Comment: I posted the image.

Comment: are you using the latest composer version

Comment: Please just find an solution for this problem. It really makes me tired.

Comment: @ Kiran Muralee I have downloaded `composer` from https://getcomposer.org/download/ recently.

Comment: @MohammadAghayari open composer.json and remove "minimum-stability": "dev"

Comment: I found a similar error post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536978/how-to-solve-the-package-not-available-in-stable-enough-version-error-of-compo

Comment: Or try updating with command  composer global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins

Comment: @ Kiran Muralee  In update with command `composer global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins` still get the same error.

Comment: open your composer.json and tell us what's inside of it or edit it like {
    "require": {
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "~1.2.0"
    }
}

Comment: Now I think the problem is in my `composer.json` in folder `C:/Users/Mohammad/AppData/Roaming/Composer`. I have to say that I had no `composer.json` file in this path before, and I copied one of my `composer.json` in there. Can you show me on `composer.json` file in example?

Comment: yup then remove the folder composer from C:/Users/Mohammad/AppData/Roaming/Composer  and try with the command composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0" again

Comment: @MohammadAghayari I have edited my answer please check

Comment: you both really helped me. I don't know how can I appreciate you.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127947/discussion-between-mohammad-aghayari-and-kiran-muralee).

Answer (score 2):

Go to the folder:

```
C:/Users/Mohammad/AppData/Roaming/Composer
```

and edit the `composer.json` file.

Make sure there are no unnecessary entries (like non-global packages).

*For example* my global composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "1.2.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.2"
    }
}
```

After removing what should not be there save it and run in console

```
composer global update
```

There is a chance you have installed some package like Yii 2 globally and that is why you get this error.

If this goes fine you can go to the project folder and retry to install Yii 2 (**don't use `global` when installing local project like this**).

Comment: @Bizley thank you very much, you really helped me. I appreciate you.

Comment: @Bizley One more question, Do I need add project path on `system variable` or not?

Comment: @MohammadAghayari no.

Comment: @Bizley please check my other problem on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554857/composer-works-every-where-except-one-project?noredirect=1#comment68348765_40554857

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use plugin to create Yii2 project, you could try fixed Bower one:

[Basic Template](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-app-basic):

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yidas/yii2-app-basic
```

[Advanced Template](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-app-advanced)

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yidas/yii2-app-advanced
```

With fixed Bower vendor, which could prevent your Composer error.

> Refer [yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip)